# Expand/Collapse Child Menu Items using jQuery in WordPress. Parent link not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have add the following jQuery to make a expand/collapse menu for my WP menu items. It's working fine. But the **problem** is when the parent menu has a link, it does not work. The child menu items under this open but it does not work. How I can fix this?

Thanks

**The JS code**

```
$('.nav-res-navigation > li:has(ul)').addClass("has-sub");
    $('.nav-res-navigation > li > a').click(function() {
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        $('.nav-res-navigation li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('.nav-res-navigation ul ul:visible').slideDown('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }
        if (checkElement.is('ul')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: What should be the behaviour if the parent item has a link? Just open up the child elements and don't open the link?

Comment: If the parent has a link, I want it to open. Since if I want just to open the child menu items, I will instead add a # in the URL field and in that the child should open below this. If the parent has a link, open this. Hope I made sense.. Or perhaps I can append a new element and show this as an arrow right to menu items and then when clicked on the arrow, the children open. Either of them will do.